# swagger-codegen-v3 mustache files custom templating not working for python-flask

Tags: python, swagger, swagger-codegen

I am trying to use custom templates on my swagger server code generated by swagger-codegen-v3 docker image.  I am using an already validated yaml file as source, a trimmed version of pet-store sample.

I downloaded all mustache files from [swagger-codegen/src/main/resources/flaskConnexion/*](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/resources/flaskConnexion) in master branch.  I took a look at v3.0.0 branch but no mustache files there.

Running generate
`docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/local swaggerapi/swagger-codegen-cli-v3 generate -i /local/openapi.yaml -l python-flask -o /local/out/python -t /local/custom_templates/`

I am getting this error message:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate model 'Address'
    at io.swagger.codegen.v3.DefaultGenerator.generateModels(DefaultGenerator.java:457)
    at io.swagger.codegen.v3.DefaultGenerator.generate(DefaultGenerator.java:788)
    at io.swagger.codegen.v3.cli.cmd.Generate.run(Generate.java:388)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.github.jknack.handlebars.HandlebarsException: local/custom_templates/model.mustache:25:29: found: '-last', expected: 'no viable alternative at input '{{^-last''
    {{name}} = {{{value}}}{{^-last}}
```

Where are the right mustache files for python-flask?

Comment: The templates for Swagger Codegen 3.x are in a separate repo: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen-generators, and the template engine is [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/) (a superset of Mustache).

Answer (score 1):

swagger-codegen-v3 mustache files are in another repository:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen-generators/

Download master version:

> git clone --depth=1
> https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen-generators.git

Go to mustache(Handlebars) files for Python and Flask:

> cd swagger-codegen-generators/src/main/resources/handlebars/pythonFlaskConnexion/

Thanks @Helen, @William